# Javascript page uses loaded code, how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I manage a course management system(Blackboard, notably)and am having an issue that I am having to fix myself because Blackboard doesn't recognize the issue. To cut it short there is an issue with rendering content in a later Service Pack in Blackboard that stems from a javascript issue. Here is my dilemma:

The frame's dimensions for this content area are set by a function called "setIFrameHeightAndWidth". I found the file in the Blackboard installation, and have enumerated its content here in a pastebin link:

http://pastebin.com/F4vVeD4v

I am constantly making edits to these 2 lines

`iframeElement.style.height = iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + frameHeight + 300 +'px';`

`iframeElement.style.width = '100%';(the 100% change I made myself)`

But when I save this file and reload the page the changes do not always stick/apply. Here is what happens when I go to the specific page that loads content calling a function in this page.

Blackboard takes that page.js file and then copies it into 3 different files(for reasons unknown), and names them 2F88F5F765F4753D1239E6FC3F898242.js, 04785022C06B7A2CD3E35B74D652973C.js, and A4B16A1C4776F93BE8C1A0BF21AB7C41.js and puts them in our external Blackboard content directory, which for my dev server is e:\blackboard\content\vi\BBLEARN\branding__js__.

Those files seem to be copies or rather take on the properties of the previous page.js file. I've confirmed this but if I sometimes reload the page the changes do not stick, here is why I think this is happening and this is my question.

If I use Chrome or Firefox's inspector to look at the resources for the page, and search for the function setIFrameHeightAndWidth, it returns all 3 files, being the 3 I mentioned above with the alphanumeric names, and inside their changes are not being reflected. I suspect that if the page was visited earlier that those 3 pages get cached and I do not want this to happen. Clearing my cache fixes the problem but I do not want to burden our user base with this if its possible not to. I noticed at the top of the page.js file, there is a section that says:

`Only include the contents of this file once - for example, if this is included in a lightbox we don't want to re-run
 * all of this - just use the loaded version.`

Is there something in the code that is preventing this from being called more than once? Is there a way I can prevent this specific page from being cache so that changes always get instantly reflected? Thank you.

Comment: The traditional way of forcing a refresh is adding a dummy query string parameter set to a GUID or something like it, that is essentially unique. So your URL would be, say, `ABCD.js?x=6ce5ced1-8ef3-4e80-aa69-f1613456ce71`. That GUID would be generated on every request, so the URL is always unique. Not sure if that's a great idea here. If you can modify the source, you could possibly just hard code some parameter to force the update once if that's all you need. That way, it would still cache in the future, but get your current updates.

Comment: I was just doing some Googling about preventing JS caching, the thing is I can't really edit the source. The source is sort of dynamically generated based on all of these things, Blackboard themeing, javascript files, embedded content, so on and so forth. There isn't any specific index.html, or default page where the source is laid out unfortunately. The idea you suggested I don't think is bad by any means, but can it be implemented into the .js file itself instead of into the source html?

Comment: I don't understand why but if I edit the 3 pages that get cached then the fixes apply instantly but never the other way around.

Comment: I hated blackboard as a student.  Glad to be done with that app.

Comment: It's decent software that unfortunately only gets like 50% backing from its company. All they want to do is market new features and sell licenses. You know what's sad is every time their support calls me at work it's always like on par with Dell(e.g. people that don't really understand what you're saying if you're pretty tech savvy.)

Comment: If your JS files are being cached, then adding a check in those files isn't going to appear on your users machines until they get the non-cached version. At which point, they won't need it anymore. If you can edit those pages that you mentioned, is it possible that you could inline some JS to get what you need? I'm not exactly sure what's getting cached here or what you are able to edit, so I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, "inline some JS". I imagine you're asking if it's possible to insert JS into the source html which is not possible. The only things I can directly edit are the .js files. 3 files get built up(the ones with the strange alphanumeric file names)using properties from a source .js file(page.js). Those are the ones that get cached. BUT. If I edit that source page and delete the 3 that get cached, then they get rebuilt properly with the changes I made to the source file, but the files already cached on client's machines aren't updating.

Comment: If I actually go to where those 3 caching files reside on our server and change them, and then go to a client's machine and refresh the page, they instantly take on the changes. But that's just weird and I don't understand why. It is a solution but I don't want to rely on those files being gone or something.